# How to click on img src in selenium - java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<a href="/index.php/leave/assignLeave" target="_self" xpath="1">
    <img src="/webres_5acde3dbd3adc6.90334155/orangehrmLeavePlugin/images/ApplyLeave.png" style="">
</a>
```

I am getting an error:

```
"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
selector","selector":"a[src='webres_5acde3dbd3adc6.90334155/orangehrmLeavePlugin/images/ApplyLeave.png']"}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try `<img>` tag instead of `<a>` because `src` is attribute of `<img>`

CSS

```
img[src='/webres_5acde3dbd3adc6.90334155/orangehrmLeavePlugin/images/ApplyLeave.png']
```

Answer (score 0):

@NarendraR's answer was in the right direction. However the value of the *src* attribute  i.e. **/webres_5acde3dbd3adc6.90334155/orangehrmLeavePlugin/images/ApplyLeave.png** looks dynamic to me. So you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='assignLeave']>[src*='ApplyLeave']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'assignLeave')]/img[contains(@src,'ApplyLeave')]")).click();
  ```